# Kudan AR Simple Sample Android does not work

Tags: android, augmented-reality, kudan

I use Kudan SDK v.1.4 on Android Studio with package: **eu.kudan.ar**

The project builds with no errors , but when i run the app, I have this error:

> 12-29 16:17:33.669 22875-22875/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   12-29 16:17:33.689 22875-22889/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
>   12-29 16:17:33.689 22875-22889/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
>   12-29 16:17:33.709 22875-22875/? W/ResourcesManager: before getResources()--------------config= {1.0 ?mcc?mnc it_IT ldltr sw800dp w1280dp h726dp 240dpi xlrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h suim:1 s.6}
>   12-29 16:17:33.719 22875-22875/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is eu.kudan.ar, real application class is null.
>   12-29 16:17:33.729 22875-22875/? W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/eu.kudan.ar/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/eu.kudan.ar/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex) with checksum 0x47fac275 in OatFile /data/data/eu.kudan.ar/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex
>   12-29 16:17:33.909 22875-22875/? I/CachedDir: file changed, refill cache - 1357
>   12-29 16:17:33.919 22875-22875/? W/linker: libKudan.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x66c50
>   12-29 16:17:33.919 22875-22875/? W/linker: libKudan.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x3
>   12-29 16:17:33.949 22875-22875/? I/kudan-ndk: **Your API key is valid**.
>   12-29 16:17:34.099 22875-22875/? I/ARFragment: onResume
>   12-29 16:17:34.159 22875-22875/? I/View: ssignParent(ViewParent parent) parent is: android.view.ViewRootImpl@2d5754ef
>   12-29 16:17:34.179 22875-22925/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   12-29 16:17:34.189 22875-22875/? I/KudanAR: screen: 1920x1128
>   12-29 16:17:34.499 22875-22875/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.media.HwCustMediaPlayerImpl
>   12-29 16:17:34.509 22875-22875/? E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>   12-29 16:17:34.519 22875-22875/? **W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
>   12-29 16:17:34.519 22875-22875/? W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)**
>   ...
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   12-29 16:17:34.519 22875-22875/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>   12-29 16:17:34.519 22875-22875/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
>   12-29 16:17:34.529 22875-22875/? E/AndroidRuntime: **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: eu.kudan.ar, PID: 22875
>                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'eu.kudan.kudan.ARWorld eu.kudan.kudan.ARImageTrackable.getWorld()' on a null object reference**
>                                                          at eu.kudan.ar.MainActivity.setup(MainActivity.java:56)
>                                                          at eu.kudan.kudan.ARView.setup(ARView.java:104)
>                                                          at eu.kudan.kudan.ARView.onSizeChanged(ARView.java:306)
>                                                          at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:15848)
>                                                          at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:15813)
>                                                          at android.view.SurfaceView.setFrame(SurfaceView.java:316)
>                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15729)
>                                                          at 
>   ....

The assets are imported well.
The problem is :

> trackableSet.loadFromAsset("demo.KARMarker");

This my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity  extends ARActivity implements ARImageTrackableListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set api key for this package name.
    ARAPIKey key = ARAPIKey.getInstance();
    key.setAPIKey("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");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void setup() {
    // create a trackable from a bundled image.
    ARImageTrackable wavesTrackable = new ARImageTrackable("waves");
    wavesTrackable.loadFromAsset("waves.png");

    // create video texture.
    ARVideoTexture videoTexture = new ARVideoTexture();
    videoTexture.loadFromAsset("waves.mp4");
    ARVideoNode videoNode = new ARVideoNode(videoTexture);

    // add video to the waves trackable.
    wavesTrackable.getWorld().addChild(videoNode);

    // load a set of trackables from a bundled file.
    ARTrackableSet trackableSet = new ARTrackableSet();
    trackableSet.loadFromAsset("demo.KARMarker");

    ARImageTracker tracker = ARImageTracker.getInstance();

    // add our trackables to the tracker.
    tracker.addTrackableSet(trackableSet);
    tracker.addTrackable(wavesTrackable);

    // create an image node.
    ARImageTrackable legoTrackable = tracker.findTrackable("lego");
    ARImageNode imageNode = new ARImageNode("BatmanLegoMovie.png");

    // make it smaller.
    imageNode.scaleBy(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    // add it to the lego trackable.
    legoTrackable.getWorld().addChild(imageNode);
}

@Override
public void didDetect(ARImageTrackable trackable) {
    Log.i("KudanSamples", "detected " + trackable.getName());
}


@Override
public void didTrack(ARImageTrackable trackable) {
    Log.i("KudanSamples", "tracked");
}

@Override
public void didLose(ARImageTrackable trackable) {
    Log.i("KudanSamples", "lost " + trackable.getName());
}
}
```

---

#### Solved

I moved the assets in /sdcard/marker/asset/ and instead of

```
trackableSet.loadFromAsset("demo.KARMarker");
```

I used method:

```
trackableSet.loadFromPath("sdcard/marker/demo.KARMarker");
```

Also license to use:

> 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

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted or answer yourself instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the name of the folder should be **assets** and not asset.

- Next, keep your assets folder inside app directory (in parallel to
  res folder).
- Now try to run your application and make sure that all the files are
  available inside that assets folder.

***Still getting that error?***

By this time it should be working well but you can make the following changes to make sure that the app is working and not getting any runtime error.

Replace this

```
ARImageNode imageNode = new ARImageNode("BatmanLegoMovie.png");
```

with

```
ARImageNode imageNode = new ARImageNode();
imageNode.initWithPath("file:///android_asset/BatmanLegoMovie.png");
```

And finally, try to track the image first. You are trying to track image, video, etc all together. Don't know if that's right or not but just to make sure that at least one thing is working properly.